# Python:Why readline() function doesn't work for file looping

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

f = open('file','r')

for line in f:
    print line 
    print 'Next line ', f.readline()
f.close()
```

This gives the following output:

```
This is the first line

Next line
That was the first line
Next line
```

Why doesn't the readline() function works inside the loop? Shouldn't it print the next line of the file?
I am using the following file as input

```
This is the first line
That was the first line
```

Comment: What version of Python are you using? When I run your code I get `ValueError: Mixing iteration and read methods would lose data`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are messing up the internal state of the file-iteration, because for optimization-reasons, iterating over a file will read it chunk-wise, and perform the split on that. The explicit `readline()`-call will be confused by this (or confuse the iteration).

To achieve what you want, make the iterator explicit:

```
 import sys

 with open(sys.argv[1]) as inf:
     fit = iter(inf)
     for line in fit:
         print "current", line
         try:
             print "next", fit.next()
         except StopIteration:
             pass
```

Answer (score 0):

USE THIS

```
for i, line in enumerate(f):
    if i == 0 :
         print line
    else:
         print 'NewLine: %s' % line
```

Comment: this is semantically not equivalent to the OPs code (modulo the problem he encounters). This does not make available the two consecutive lines in the loop body.

Comment: @deets exactly, should have used .next()