# Python: copy a block bordered by a specific line to a new file

Tags: python, string, file, python-2.7, copy

I am very new in programming, but now I need it to a project, so I did some python courses in "sos". First of all: sorry for my English, though I hope you can understand me.

So one of my task is that I have numerous files which contains the followings: a protein (approx the first 56 lines), and several blocks which start like this: "HEADER crosscluster.^^^.^^^.pdb"
I have to choose the ones where the "^^^" in front of .pdb is greater than 016 (i think i could do this part). Then I have to copy the protein and one of these chosen blocks to a new file, doing this for each chosen blocks. So one file should contains only the protein and 1 block starts with "HEADER crosscluster.***.***.pdb".

I don't get any error message, just doesn't happen anything.

So... the script (:$):

```
    #!/usr/bin/python

import os
import sys
import re



def split_file(phrase1, phrase2, my_file):
    n = 1
    my_list = []
    for phrase1, phrase2 in my_file.readlines():
        if not re.search(r"(.*)(.pdb)", line):
            my_list.append(line)
            with open("output"+str(n)+".pdb","w") as out_file:
                for item in my_list:
                    out_file.write(item)
        else:
            if my_list:
                my_list = []
                n += 1
        my_file.close()
        out_file.close()       


for dirname, dirnames, filenames in os.walk("/home/georgina/FTmaperedmenyek"):
    for filename in filenames:
        full_name = str(os.path.join(dirname, filename)) 
        if filename.endswith(".pdb"):
            searching = open(full_name, "r")
            for line in searching:
                pld = "HEADER crosscluster.***.***.pdb"
                protein = "HEADER protein"
                if pld in line and int(pld[24:27]) > int(016):
                    split_file(protein, pld, searching)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not getting any error from your code, that means the function - `split_file()` - is not being called at all, and this is because of -

```
int(016)
```

When you prefix a number with 0 in Python 2.x , you are defining it as an octal number. Example -

```
>>> int(016)
14
```

`14` is the decimal representation for octal number `0o16` .

You need to do -

```
int(pld[24:27]) > int(16)
```

---

Secondly, I do not think this would work - `for phrase1, phrase2 in my_file.readlines():` - This would throw error if there are more or less than 2 lines.

It is not recommended to use `.readline()` when iterating inside the function. Why? Check this question out - [Python:Why readline() function doesn't work for file looping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32181440/pythonwhy-readline-function-doesnt-work-for-file-looping)

You should again iterate over the file, instead of using `.readlines()`. And you should do -

```
for line in my_file:
    #If you wanted to check if phrase1 and phrase2 are in the line do the below -
    if phrase1 in line and phrase2 in line:
        #rest of the logic.
```